# How to implement webservice version gateway with Apache Camel, CXF and Spring Boot

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf

I am currently working on a project where I use Apache Camel, CXF for my WebService implementation. On top of that I use Spring Boot (with tomcat embedded).

I developed different CXF Endpoints for each of my web Service version and they can be accessed in following manner
`http://myserver.com/service/V1`or `http://myserver.com/service/V2`. This is all working fine unless I got requirement to make these services working under one url `http://myserver.com/service/CommonVersion` and route it to specific version based on a xpath.

I don't really know how to configure and then dispatch a web service request from a common entry point to version specific entry point.

I want to provide some some setup that I have for my application:
cxf-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd  http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceV1"
                 address="/service/V1" serviceName="s:Service" serviceClass="com.myservice.v1.service" xmlns:s="http://com.myservice/ServiceV1">
   <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="allowStreaming" value="false" />
   </cxf:properties>
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

  <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceV2" address="/service/V2" serviceName="s:Service" serviceClass="com.myservice.v2.service" xmlns:s="http://com.myservice/ServiceV2">
   <cxf:properties>
      <entry key="allowStreaming" value="false" />
   </cxf:properties>
  </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
</beans>
```

and sample route defined for my cxf endpoint

```
@Component
public class ServiceV1 extends SpringRouteBuilder {
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("cxf:bean:serviceV1").to("mock:processFurther")
  }

}
```

My Application Configuration is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "/cxf-context.xml" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
        SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return super.configure(application).sources(Application.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    CXFServlet servlet = new CXFServlet();
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/*");
  }
}
```

Comment: I found a blog post about similar issue: http://waterback.github.io/blog/2012/03/02/easy-handmade-ws-addresssing-with-apache-camel/ however presented solution is rellying on jetty and it opens two ports. Problem description is very similar

Comment: I belive serviceCommon endpoint doesn't have to be cxf. It could be an netty-http endpoint....

Answer (score 0):

You surely know that with CXF and Camel, the implementations of the services are made by the routes themselves.

I would rename what you call "ServiceV1" ("extends SpringRouteBuilder") simply as something like "Routes" (because all the routes are in there and not just one service), and implement this like so -- just an example to make things realistic:

```
@Component
public class MyRoutes extends SpringRouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("cxf:bean:serviceV1")
                .to("direct:v1");

        from("cxf:bean:serviceV2")
                .to("direct:v2");

        from("cxf:bean:serviceCommon")
                .choice()
                    .when(header("version").isEqualTo("v1"))
                        .to("direct:v1")
                    .otherwise()
                        .to("direct:v2")
                .end();

        from("direct:v1")
                .beanRef("paymentservicev1", "buy");

        from("direct:v1")
                .beanRef("paymentservicev2", "buy");

    }
}
```

Here I do not switch on an xpath but on a header value -- well you get the idea. Is that want you are looking for?

Comment: In theory that would work however let's consider following scenario: V1 and V2 are not compatible and you are mapping CXF request to an object one from package v1 the other from package v2. You would also like to have validation of XML turn on (at least in QA). what dataformat type should you use on serviceCommon cxfEndpoint? How to still validate request for V1 and V2 although you are going through serviceCommon?